# Flutter: Access SharedPreferences Provider / ChangeNotifier in a Stream Class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I've looked around in StackoverFlow and was not able to find myself a solution to this.
Scenario:
I have a Flutter SharedPreferences Provider with ChangeNotifier Class, that will get updated with the current Logged In User info.

Simplified content:

```
class SharedPreferences {
  final String userId;
  final String userName;

  SharedPreferences({
    @required this.userId,
    @required this.userName,
  });
}
class SharedPreferencesData with ChangeNotifier {
  var _sharedPreferencesData = SharedPreferences(
    userId: 'testUserId',
    userName: 'testUserName',
  );}
```

And a database.dart file with Class containing DataBaseServices to get FireStore Streams from Snapshots:

```
class DatabaseService {
  final CollectionReference companiesProfilesCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('companiesProfiles');

  List<CompanyProfile> _companiesProfilesFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return CompanyProfile(
        docId: doc.documentID,
        companyName: doc.data['companyName'] ?? '',
        maxLocationsNumber: doc.data['maxLocationsNumber'] ?? 0,
        maxUsersNumber: doc.data['maxUsersNumber'] ?? 0,
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  Stream<List<CompanyProfile>> get getCompaniesProfiles {
    return companiesProfilesCollection
        .where('userId', isEqualTo: _userIdFromProvider) 
        // My problem is above -----
        .snapshots()
        .map(_companiesProfilesFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

I Don't want to fetch the entire Stream data as it could be massive for other Streams, I just want to pass the userID under .where('userId', isEqualTo:_userIdFromProvider).

- I couldn't access the context in this class to get the data from the Provider
- Couldn't send the userId to getCompaniesProfiles getter, as getter don't take parameters
- And if I convert this getter to a regular method, I wont be able to send the userID to it, as this has to run under **void main() {runApp(MyApp());} / return MultiProvider(providers: [**  and By then I cannot call fetch the sharedPreferences with a context that does not contain the provider info ...
- Couldn't figure out how to receive the context as a constructor in this class, when I did, I got the following *Only static members can accessed in initializers* in class DatabaseService.

I'm still a beginner, so I would appreciate if you could share with me the best approach to handle this.
Thank you!

*********** Re-Edited by adding the below: **************
I'm trying to implement the same scenario, here is my code:
Main file:

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<SpData>(
      create: (context) => SpData(),
    ),
    ProxyProvider<SpData, DS>(
      create: (context) => DS(),
      update: (ctx, spData, previousDS) {
        print('ChangeNotifierProxyProvider RAN');
        previousDS.dbData = spData;
        return previousDS;
      },
    ),
  ],
```

SP File:

```
class SP {
  final String companyId;
  SP({
    @required this.companyId,
  });
}

class SpData with ChangeNotifier {
  var _sPData = SP(
    companyId: '',
  );
  void setCompanyId(String cpID) {
    final newSharedPreferences = SP(
      companyId: cpID,
    );
    _sPData = newSharedPreferences;
    print('_spData companyId:${_sPData.companyId}');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String get getCompanyId {
    return _sPData.companyId;
  }
}
```

DS file:

```
class DS with ChangeNotifier {
  SpData dbData;
  void printCompanyId() {
    var companyId = dbData.getCompanyId;
    print('companyId from DataBase: $companyId');
  }
}
```

The SpData dbData; inside Class DS does not update. I've added the prints to figure out what is running and what is not. When I run my code, the print function in main.dart file print('ChangeNotifierProxyProvider RAN'); does not run.

What am I missing? Why ChangeNotifierProxyProvider is not being triggered, to update dbData inside DS file? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ProxyProvider` for this purpose.

`ProxyProvider` is a provider that builds a value based on other providers.

You said you have a `MultiProvider`, so I guess you have `SharedPreferencesData` provider in this `MultiProvider` and then `DatabaseService` provider. What you need to do is use `ProxyProvider` for `DatabaseService` instead of a regular provider and base it on the `SharedPreferencesData` provider.

Here is an example:

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<SharedPreferencesData>(
      create: (context) => SharedPreferencesData(),
    ),
    ProxyProvider<SharedPreferencesData, DatabaseService>(
      create: (context) => DatabaseService(),
      update: (context, sharedPreferencesData, databaseService) {
        databaseService.sharedPreferencesData = sharedPreferencesData;
        return databaseService;
      },
      dispose: (context, databaseService) => databaseService.dispose(),
    ),
  ],
  child: ...
```

Here is what happens in the code snippet above:

1. `ProxyProvider` calls `update` everytime `SharedPreferencesData` changes.
2. `DatabaseService` gets its `sharedPreferencesData` variable set inside `update`.

Now that you have access to `sharedPreferencesData` inside the `DatabaseService` instance, you can do what you want easily.

Comment: This approach is totally legit. But it did not work for me, it is maybe related to some wrong implementation I am doing, here's why:
When sharedPreferencesData is passed for the first time to DatabaseService, it is empty.
I am not using notifyListeners in sharedPreferencesData because of an error I am receiving: error on build: cannot notifyListeners => setState => rebuild while the app is building.
Yet my app is working fine without the notifyListeners, cause sharedPreferencesData contains variables that will only get updated on app run and login.
So I'm stuck again, as how to fix this.

Comment: I think you should fix the issue with your `notifyListeners`. That error tells me you make a call to `notifyListeners` within your `build` method which is wrong.

Comment: Hi Shahin, I've solved my notifyListeners issue using WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback. Now sharedPreferencesData  should notify listeners, and therefore get updated to notify the proxy provider .. 
I have done the following:

Comment: ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: SharedPreferencesData(),
        ),
        ProxyProvider<SharedPreferencesData, DatabaseService>(
          create: (context) => DatabaseService(),
          update: (context, sharedPreferencesData, databaseService) {
            databaseService.sharedPreferencesData = sharedPreferencesData;
            return databaseService;
          },
//          dispose: (context, databaseService) => databaseService.dispose(),
        ),
Noting that, dispose gave me: The method 'dispose' isn't defined for the type 'DatabaseService'.

Comment: Can you tell me how to implement Dispose in DatabaseService?
And in DatabaseService:
class DatabaseService {
  SharedPreferencesData sharedPreferencesData;
  final sPData = SharedPreferencesData().getSharedPreferencesData();
.... }
I've added some print code in a DatabaseService StreamProvider, But when running my app, I get the following:
I/flutter ( 6795): sPData.companyId: is empty
I/flutter ( 6795): sPData.companyId: is empty
Running 2 times, maybe one when the app loads at first, and another after notifylisteners. 
But sPData.companyId still remains empty in DatabaseService

Comment: You are supposed to dispose of your resources in `dispose` method in order to prevent memory leaks. If you don't have any resources to dispose of then just create an empty `dispose` method or you could just stop calling `dispose` method in proxy provider.

Comment: As for your other issue, I can't tell much without seeing more of your code.

Comment: I've edited my post, adding a very simple code just to make things working then applying it to my app. If you can just check what is still wrong. Thanks!

Comment: The thing is `update` method is supposed to get called only if `SharedPreferencesData` itself is changed, not one of its attributes. So don't explicitly assign one of its attributes to `DatabaseService`. Assign `SharedPreferencesData` itself to `DatabaseService` as an attribute and use getter on it whenever you need company id. Take a look at the `update` method in my answer and you will understand.

Comment: I just don't get it, and can't make it work. in main.dart the ChangeNotifierProxyProvider / update method is never running whatever I do, disregarding what is inside, the print function just don't run. I'm a beginner, I really need to solve this, and I have been trying for long now ... I've re-edited my question, please find a very simplified version and let me know what's wrong.

Comment: The only mistake in your updated code is using `ProxyProvider` instead of `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider`. I tested your code and it works perfectly. I am guessing the reason your `update` method is not called is because you are not using `Provider.of<DS>(context)` anywhere. Keep in mind create/update callbacks are lazy-loaded, which means they are called the first time the value is read instead of the first time the provider is created. If you want to disable this feature you can add `lazy: false` to your providers.

Comment: That is exactly what I did yesterday, using lazy:false made it work. and then I reconfigured my code to work without a lazy config. Thank you Shahin! you did great!

Comment: One more thing, I've used `var dB = Provider.of<DatabaseService>(context, listen: false);` . When trying to get my List of CompaniesProfiles using `var cp= dB.getCompaniesProfiles ;` the cp type would be Stream<List<CompanyProfile>> instead of <List<CompanyProfile>> as I always got before from DataBaseServices.
Noting that I was able to access the sharedpre data using `dB.sPData.getSharedPreferencesData().companyId` . But now how would I get my Stream/Lists from DatabaseService ?

Comment: should I modify something in myCompanyProfile Provider?:
`StreamProvider<List<CompanyProfile>>.value( value: DatabaseService().getCompaniesProfiles, initialData: List(),),`

Comment: Updated to: 
`StreamProvider<List<CompanyProfile>>.value(value: Provider.of<DatabaseService>(bCtx, listen: false).getCompaniesProfiles,initialData: List(),),`
It seems to be working, But lots of errors as my entire code was based directly on DataBaseService().
Is this the correct approach? before I totally convert my entire app to listen to that single  `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<SharedPreferencesData, DatabaseService>`? .. meaning that I should always use this provider to access DataBaseService + SharedPreferencesData instance, instead of using DataBaseService directly?